# Finding the name of: Mechanical toggle actuator utilizing single direction of force (pull only/push only)

Tags: actuator

*Preface: I have no formal experience in design or mechanical engineering. I am simply a backyard mechanic looking to see if a particular assembly exists as an off-the-shelf product before designing and producing a custom one-off part.*

The part I am looking for is similar to the floor mounted parking brakes that you could push into a locked position, then push again and have the device return via spring. Except more specifically, something that operates in a pull-only configuration (via a pull cable) and would have only 2 major positions, instead of the dozen or so ratchet positions of a parking brake.

Operation is something like this:
You pull a cable, it pulls some mechanical rod a certain distance, and locks the the rod into that position. Then to disengage the mechanism, you would pull the cable again, which would free the rod from the locked position and a spring would return the assembly to the disengaged position.

The application is fairly general, but I am specifically looking to use it as a way to operate a fuel valve via pull-only cable, or a gear shifter fork via a pull-only cable.

I'm having a hard time finding similar assemblies on google. Looking up things like "mechanical toggle actuator", "cylindrical linear ratcheting", or "barrel cam toggle actuator" doesn't bring up any parts that could be used in this manner.

Is what I'm describing an off-the-shelf part anywhere? Or am I out of luck for an existing product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question indicates an option for push-only, while the body of the question references pull-only. One could argue for a simple means to invert the motion, hence this answer.

Parker Pens invented a ball point retraction system that is in common use today. [Engineerguy on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhVw-MHGv4s) provides a very clear explanation of the workings of this push to engage, push to retract mechanism.

Another YouTuber, [This Old Tony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_wPH904a_8) has a much longer (18 minutes) video of a DIY push-latch mechanism.

With a little bit of exploration and modification, your answer may be found in one of these or similar videos. I'm partial to the drunken cone/triangle toT mentions in his video.

Yet another YouTube creator, [Coffredom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VA7UGVCpcFk) provides for a 3D printed mechanism, which exposes the design and structure for more clarification. The comments section includes an untested link for the 3D printing files. Screen capture below from the linked video.

[image: diy latch video screen capture]

Comment: That's a very neat mechanism. Looks pretty simple to change that design to a pull configuration. Thanks for the response!

Comment: If you find the answer useful, click on the up-arrow to vote positive response. If you believe this to be the best answer, click on the accept feature. I found your question to be clearly stated and displays some research effort, hence my upvote to your question.